# If there was a black hole on earth, what would it look like?

Tags: black-holes, earth

If an answer does exist, I'd love to hear it. I'm trying to incorporate a doomed earth story in something I'm writing, and the end of the world I'm going for is a black hole.

Let's say the black hole was created in the Philippines (I chose it because it's on the equator). Here's [a map](http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/world_maps/world_pol495.jpg) for reference.

If I was standing 90 degrees of that, in Kenya, or if I was standing 180 degrees of that, in Mexico; what would I see in those two separate instances? What if I was standing in Japan above it, or in Australia below it?

Let's also say I was riding a boat towards the source of the black hole. Unlike most imagined scenarios where I am orbiting the black hole and slowly falling into it, this time I'm no longer orbiting it - I'm getting sucked into it instead. I'm imagining that the black hole will "half" be inside Earth and "half" will be in the atmosphere. But as it pulls me in, what will it look like to me (if I was massless, so no tidal forces)? It's probably not going to be a black hemisphere sticking out of the ground. Light will be lensed around it in some way so as to appear like a hole in the air.

Also, if the black hole was very small, it probably won't have a strong gravitational pull, and assuming it doesn't disappear, you'd be able to look at it (or at least, its effect on the light in its surroundings). Of course, as you approach it, it would still have an event horizon, so spacetime would still be warped if you're near enough and the surroundings will still experience tidal forces.

As the black hole gains mass, it will get larger, and so its event horizon will increase. If I was standing in Kenya and the event horizon "washes over me," (as in a water wave) what will I see?

I've so far imagined that, at least when seen from outer space, there will be a hole on the ground and light will be lensed around it. When you are on the ground, though, it becomes a bit harder to imagine.

I do hope someone can lend me a hand!

**Edit:** Someone had previously answered this question, but I'm not sure why it's been deleted. It was pointed out to me, though, that a black hole cannot stay in place. So an additional question for me is, does that mean it is impossible to be standing still, and the event horizon "washes over you"?

**Edit2:** Here's a guiding thought experiment that could answer the question. Imagine that you are in outer space directly above the black hole, looking at the black hole that is on the earth's surface. Can you imagine what it would look like? It would simply be a hole with the surrounding light gravitationally lensed around it (possibly lensing the entire earth if it's big enough - but let's say it's not).

Now imagine that you are on the direct opposite of where you were above - you're right behind the black hole this time, looking directly at the black hole but unable to see it because the earth is blocking your view.

Now try to imagine, from the second image, rotate the earth into the first image. I find it a bit hard to do. Just as the black hole is appearing as you rotate the earth, how would the light be lensed?

Comment: As usual, women and minorities will be hardest hit.

Comment: This is a great question. I don't know if anybody will have a good answer. A black hole the mass of the Earth would be around 1/5 of a millimeter in diameter. It would be hard for the event horizon to "wash over" you. And I suspect not everything would be "sucked into" it immediately ... things would start orbiting around it (close things at enormous speeds).

Comment: @PeterShor I think $4GM_\oplus/c^2$ comes out to a diameter of 1.8 cm? Still, your point stands - it would be small.

Comment: @Chris: you're right ... I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2743/2451

Comment: I deleted my answer because I wrote it hastily and it wasn't very good. Others have since done a better job than me, so I'll just mention the link in my answer to simulations of falling into a black hole: http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/intro.html

Comment: There are already several science-fiction novels about black holes eating the Earth. most notable are "Earth" by David Brin and "Dragon's Egg" by Robert Forward.

Comment: No long. It would not be visible too long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An interesting and horrifying possibility for your book could be that of a tiny black hole with negligible mass relative to the mass of the Earth. It would silently sink into the ground, completely unnoticed. It would make damped oscillations around the center of the Earth until eventually staying within the nucleus. There it would stay unnoticed, slowly growing like a parasite. The Earth radius would start to diminish, and thus the crust would have to adapt by means of earthquakes - very weak at first, but of increasing frequency and strength. Eventually, chains of volcanoes would appear along giant fault lines, heating and poisoning the atmosphere, bringing total obliteration. After that, the Earth would continue shrinking until all that was left would be a tiny black hole with little more than one Earth mass in the place where our planet was. And the Moon would stay there as a horrified witness of the catastrophe.

Nothing on Earth would be able to stop the process and save us. Nothing except *Chuck Norris*.

---

Note: Classical GR black holes are fully determined with just three values: mass, electric charge and angular momentum (No-hair theorem). If the charge is large enough in the black hole of your novel, then the hero might be able to confine it by using strong magnetic fields.

Comment: There should be a "Science-Fiction" tag to clearly distinguish this kind of phantasy questions.

Comment: Hi Eduardo. You're quite right. But, a "sci-fi" tag wouldn't be so nice for us to keep around coz, there's already scifi.SE to deal with those. Instead, a "creative" or "what-if-happened" tags would be so nice. Feel free to post in meta if you like a discussion on creating tags. BTW, Nice pic and one more thing - your last name ends with "Guerras". I think I saw some other thing before ;-)

Comment: That's a good detail. But it "cops out" of one of the more colorful guide questions I asked, which is, is it impossible for the event horizon to "wash over you"? 

@Crazy Buddy - You're right. I'll add that tag (if it already exists).

Comment: @markovchain: Please try not to add new tags. We already have enough tags, that we're giving some synonyms and do a clean-up *nowadays*. We mostly prefer to discuss in the meta before creating new tags (especially these days) ;-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy - no need to worry there. I'm a very new user, so tag creation is impossible for me right now. That's why I said if it already exists, and it turns out that it doesn't yet :)

Comment: @markovchain, unfortunately, the phrasal verb "to wash over" is new to me. Let me google...

Comment: Hey Eduardo, Hope you like my English transformation. BTW, If you require further corrections on your posts, the more efficient way is to add a comment below your post, so that it reveals a "side-note".

Comment: @markovchain, which of the three possible meanings of "wash over" from [this link](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/wash_over) applies here? The first or the third one?

Comment: The third one. I was imagining an analogy, which I realize just now I should have mentioned in the question. I was comparing the event horizon to a water wave washing over someone on earth.

Comment: In any case, all this is fun but nonsensical, since there is no way of creating such a small classical GR black hole (I am not talking about more advanced particle physics).

Comment: At least, not in nature. You need several times the mass of the Sun and at least several million years of nuclear reactions.

Comment: That's actually a very interesting point. A small, classical black hole would be containable in a field. I can imagine how the electric charge will be needed. Could you expound a little on why the spin would be necessary, though?

Comment: @markovchain, I have gone too far with that statement. I erase that comment. A bit of fantasy is fun, but one cannot go too far without making calculations. The rotation has to do with real black holes in active galaxies, but it doesn't apply here. Let's simply say that, if your tiny BH has electric charge, the hero of the novel can try to confine it with strong magnetic fields.

Comment: Science fiction with the scenario includes "The Hole Man" by Larry Niven, *The Golden Globe* by John Varley and other that don't come right to mind.

Comment: But wouldn't a black hole small enough to fall through the Earth unnoticed glow bright with Hawking radiation (it's inversely proportional to mass) and soon end it's life in a really huge explosion?

Answer (score 3):

There are some [visualizations of what it would look like to travel past the event horizon](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/schw.html), assuming you survive the process of course.

This video gives you an idea of what the black hole looks like. What you see is a distortion of everything around you, as bit like looking through curved glass.

Unfortunately these videos aren't set on Earth; I'm sure the hole chewing up Earth would look spectacular, but I don't know how long this might last. I suspect things would get pretty hot as matter is compressed on its way towards the hole.

Comment: Why do people think that Earth mass (centimeter-size) black holes would eat the Earth, rather than breaking up the Earth into little tiny bits, which all end up in orbit around the hole? Do you have any actual evidence that the hole eats Earth, or is this just intuition?

Comment: @PeterShor I didn't mean to claim it will be consumed in its entirety, nor that bits of the earth will fall into the hole in a straight line. I'm sure lots of the mass will end up orbiting.

Comment: @Peter Shor Because; the speed of Earth's rotation (the mass that will fall into the black-hole), is much lower than the orbital velocity required at the earth radius.  Collisions between chunks might knock SOME of the mass up to orbital velocity or even escape velocity, but not gravity alone.

Comment: @Glurth: It's much lower than the orbital velocity required at earth radius, but the Swartzchild radius of the black hole is a few ***centimeters***. And the angular velocity of the Earth is much larger than the orbital velocity required for a centimeter-size object.

Comment: @Peter Shor  I thought orbital velocity increases as radius decreases. sqrt(GM/r)

Comment: @Glurth: In orbits, velocity is not preserved. [Angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) is: $L = rmv = m\sqrt{GMr}$.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of the question is wrong: if you dropped a small black hole (one less than the mass of the Earth) into the Earth, only a small fraction of Earth's mass would end up in the black hole.

The maximum angular momentum of a black hole of mass $M$ is $\frac{G M^2}{c}$. For the Earth's mass, this is around $7.9 \times 10^{30}$ kg m$^2$/s.

The angular momentum of the earth is around $7.1 \times 10^{33}$ kg m$^2$/s.

That angular momentum has to go somewhere, and the only place it could go is into pieces of the Earth that either end up orbiting the black hole or escaping to infinity. These pieces would presumably comprise nearly all of the mass of the Earth.

I don't know exactly what would happen. Probably, the Earth would eventually be destroyed, but I really don't know how fast or how it would happen. Whatever happens, you are probably going to get killed in some way other than being sucked into the black hole.

Answer (score 1):

In this, I have taken the assumption that the singularity is created within the atmosphere, perhaps by an experiment or some such, rather than a wandering black hole, and therefore starts life with much less mass than the earth. A naturally created black hole travelling in space would generally be far more massive, having been created from a collapsing star. in the latter case, the planet would simply be shredded as it nears the event horizon, killing everyone on the planet, or possibly just swallowing the earth in seconds, dependent on the relative motions and trajectories of the two

The thing about a singularity is that any matter which falls within its event horizon is consumed, and from an external frame of reference instantly becomes part of the mass of the singularity. Any mass which exists within the atmosphere of earth will move towards the earth at an acceleration of 10 m/s/s. A singularity would not be slowed by air resistance, as it would draw in any air molecules that contacted the event horizon, rather than displace them.

Also, due to the curvature of the Earth, nothing within the atmosphere near the philipines would ever be visible from 90 or 180 degrees away in any direction.

Therefore this singularity would fall rapidly to earth, where it would proceed through the crust experiencing drag equivalent to the ability of whatever matter it contacts to resist, albeit briefly, being torn apart by the singularity pulling in any matter contacting the event hozizon. once through the crust to the liquid part of the core, it would accelerate again, initially passing directly through the gravitational centre of the earth repeatedly back and forth, until it consumes enough matter to shift the centre of gravity of the earth, at which point, the singularity and the earth would begin to orbit their common centre of gravity. This would result in erratic changes as the singularity consumes matter in intermittent pulses, as it passes in and out of voids created by it previous motions.

as the singularity consumes more and more of the planet, the earth would break up under the vibrations caused by the wobbling motion within, speeding the growth of the singularity, as the remains of the crust fall inwards to the common centre of gravity, where they will be consumed by the ever growing black hole. when the earth is fully consumed, the black hole would continue to orbit the sun in its place, until it consumes enough orbiting debris to begin a spiral orbit towards the sun, likely collecting venus and mercury on the way. when it eventually hits the sun, it will repeat the process on a much larger scale, either consuming the star entirely, leaving a black hole in its place, or potentially destabilising the sun enough that it goes supernova before the black hole can consume it.

If the singularity had enough mass to survive longer than a few seconds after creation, without evaporating, I would expect it to destroy the earth completely in just a few hours, with all life being wiped out quite early on due to the cataclysmic disruption to the crust.

If a living person were to enter the event horizon, they would die, torn apart by the forces inside. However, they would feel nothing as the electrical nerve impulses from the affected nerves would never reach the brain, themselves being pulled into the centre of the singularity.

Comment: Your answer really simplifies things too much.  If the black hole were tiny it would be radiating much faster than it would be accreting new mass.  It could probably radiate so much that it blasts the earth with radiation and sterilizes all life.