# How large would a black hole have to be do devour a rocky planet such as Earth?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

I had the idea of using a black hole as a weapon to engulf inhabited planets. I wanted to know the minimum mass required to absorb more than its hawking radiation worth of energy each second, which would rapidly snowball into the absorption of of the body. The only bit that I don't know how to solve for is "How can we calculate the distance from which an object would impact a point mass given a fixed amount of time?" Thanks!

Comment: Related: [What would happen if somebody dropped a small black hole into the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/424929) and [How fast a (relatively) small black hole will consume the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2743)

Comment: @safesphere I was assuming that the black hole was at ground level, and the rotation of the Earth would put it on a trajectory that would likely absorb the planet fairly quickly. Also, impact would be the point in time at which the object would come in contact with the event horizon, but a simple formula for the time required to reach a given distance would be fine.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly those links don't really answer my question. But thanks anyway!