# I would like to know, what would happen if a primordial black hole mass of Earth, would impact with the Earth

Tags: black-holes

Sorry for any mistakes, I'm Italian 
Hello everyone, I'm writing a novel, in which the Earth is devastated by enormous geological cataclysms (something like the end of the world), and to implement my cataclysm, I thought of a primordial black hole with a mass similar to that of the Earth. At first I thought to stabilize the black hole inside the Earth, but it would have destroyed the planet, and I do not want to destroy it; or so thought to pass away from one side to the Earth from the black hole, causing very powerful shock waves, which first pierce the mantle, causing the eruption of every volcano on earth, and then the crust collide, greatly destabilizing the tectonic plates , causing massive earthquakes on a global scale, and triggering the formation of giant tsunami impacting against every continent. such a scenario is likely, or not. 
ps: I hope that the question is connection to physics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If there was a black hole on earth, what would it look like?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51700/)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55143/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2743/2451